# Comparison of the mean of a binary variable from two independent sets

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, spss, mean, binary-data

I have two sets of data, one is akin to high performing companies, and the other contains low performing companies.

I want to compare the mean of a binary value. For instance, "CEO has a bachelor degree".

Let's say the high performing companies have these values for this variable

```
[1 0 1 0 1 1 0] => µ = 4 / 7 = 0,57
```

The low performing companies could have something like

```
[1 0 1 0 1 0 0] => µ = 3 / 7 = 0,43
```

Now if I would like to know if these means are statistically different from each other what test should I use? My first thought would be to use a t-test, but I assume this is no option due to the fact my data is not normally distributed. I'm intending to use SPSS for analysis.

Answer (score 0):

To compare the means of two samples one would use a t-test. **NOTE:** a t-test makes no assumptions on the distribution of the data, it only assumes the **residuals** of the model (differences in case of a two sample t-test) are normally distributed.

If this does not hold then you can use a non-parametric version of the t-test, such as Mann Whitney U test.

**NOTE2:** yours is a binary variable, so by taking the mean you are estimating the proportion (proportion of people with degree), so for this you can use a proportion test as well.

Comment: In the case of the two-sample t-test, the standard $iid$ normal assumption on the residuals is equivalent to the two groups being normal.

Comment: @Dave How are those two assumptions equivalent? You can get normal residuals even if the two separate distributions are not normal.

Comment: Are they $iid?$

Comment: @Dave The two distributions? Yes.

Comment: Care to post an example, perhaps a simulation in software like R or Python?

Answer (score 0):

A two-sample t-test is an option here and is likely to perform decently. While the t-test does have assumptions about the two groups each having normal distributions, the test is rather robust to violations of that assumed normality.

**However**, you know your variables to have binomial (Bernoulli, even) distributions. Consequently, you can use a test specific to such distributions, and you do not have to rely on the t-test being rather robust.

A proportion chi-squared test is one of the popular ways to test this. I like the G-test but not enough to get into a heated debate about G vs chi-squared.